# trying to delete data from a database via my website but the data is not being deleted

Tags: php

I am trying to delete data from the database and the code is not throwing me any errors but the data is not being deleted

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require('../../../../includes/conn.inc.php');
require('../includes/functions.inc.php');
// sanitize user variables
$sFixtureID = safeInt($_POST['fixtureID']);
// prepare SQL
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM matchFixtures WHERE fixtureID = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $sFixtureID);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
header("Location: ../../protected_page.php");
// redirect browser
exit;
// make sure no other code executed
?>
```

Comment: Your `safeInt` function might be sanitizing `$_POST['fixtureID']` to `0` (zero). `echo` the variable and see what value it is.

Comment: *the code is not throwing me any errors*...maybe because you do not use `try catch` for sql exceptions